# Passing URL of the active tab to my site handler

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I suspect this is a total newbie question, but I seem to be missing the basics here. I am NOT new to coding and have a lifetime of experience (27 years) with various languages, but the plugin process is eluding me.

I have developed custom bookmarking system in php & js, it works great and I've been using it for months  as I develop it.

I simply want to get the url of the page in the active tab and pass it to my php handler. I want my web site script return the html form into the popup. I can think of a thousand ways that "should" work.

ALL the code examples I am finding seem to over-complicate what should be a simple task.

In short I just want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var loadurl = "http://my.site.com?theUrl=" + window.location;
location.href = loadurl;
//-->
</script>
```

And have that page show in the popup. So far I'm at a loss. Even tried ajax calls etc.
Can somebody clue me in on how to achieve this simple task? Maybe I can get started writing extensions with the info.

For the record, most of the examples I have found are deprecated under manifest 2.0

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? "get the url of the page in the active tab"? "web site script return the html form into the popup" (whatever this means)? What do you mean by "And have that page show in the popup"? Display the bookmarked page in the *browser action* popup?

Comment: Your question is very valid, because I think I have no idea. I suppose I am expecting the popup to behave like a browser window and it doesn't?

Comment: The popup is treated like a view of the extension. It has access to higher privilege extension APIs, and therefore, you cannot display arbitrary content in it. Embed the page in a `<iframe>` within the pop-up, and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manifest 2.0 introduces a new feature [contentSecurityPolicy](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html). All external resources are blocked by default. For the best practice, you should include all needed asset files in the extension. The communication between your extension and your service (php side) is only data using XHR2.

So, In order to make bookmark extension work, I guess you need to something like this:

1. Add your service's domain to permissions array

   ```
   {
       ...
       permissions: ['*://my.site.com/*', 'tabs']
   }
   ```
2. Move all javascript from `popup.html` to `popup.js`. In `popup.js`, You create a ajax request to your bookmarking service. [More document here](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr.html)

   ```
   function addBookmark(url) {
       var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
       xhr.open("GET", "http://my.site.com/new_bookmark.php?url=" + encodeURIComponent(url), true);

       xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
               var resp = xhr.responseText;
               // handle service result here
           }
       }
       xhr.send();
   }

   chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
       addBookmark(tab.url);
   });
   ```

Comment: Excellent Answer, though I seem to be really lost on the "Handle Service Result"

Comment: Doc says I gotta lay off the keyboard for a few days. I'll get back on the project when my CTS calms down. Thanks for the help gang!